# How to do statistics collection in MDBs state of the art?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

I have multiple MDBs (and plenty of mdb instances) as consumers for messages. I have to collect certain statistics inside these Beans and send them every X (currently 30) seconds to a JMS destination.

**Is it ok to do this in the bean itself?**

for example: the bean gathers the data localy and has a writeStatistic() method that uses the @Scheduled annotation.

**Is it possible to do the statistic stuff centralised?**

a central bean collects all statistics data from all bean instances and sends it of. If this is possible, how can it be done?

### **EDIT**

I solved my task by writing a singleton session bean that looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
@Asynchronous
public class StatisticsCollector {

    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger>> statistics = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger>>();

    public void trackDatum(int projectId, String property, int increment) {
        LOG.debug("Tracking datum: project: " + projectId + ", property: " + property + ", increment: " + increment);

        // get statistics for project
        ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> productstats;
        if (!statistics.containsKey(projectId)) {
            synchronized (statistics) {
                if (!statistics.containsKey(projectId)) {
                    productstats = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
                    statistics.put(projectId, productstats);
                } else {
                    productstats = statistics.get(projectId);
                }
            }
        } else {
            productstats = statistics.get(projectId);
        }

        // get current counter for property
        AtomicInteger value;
        if (!productstats.containsKey(property)) {
            synchronized (productstats) {
                if (!productstats.containsKey(property)) {
                    value = new AtomicInteger();
                    productstats.put(property, value);
                } else {
                    value = productstats.get(property);
                }
            }
        } else {
            value = productstats.get(property);
        }

        // increment
        value.addAndGet(increment);
    }

    @Schedule(minute = "*", hour = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
    public void sendStatistics() {
        // send statistics to remote consumer via JMS
    }
}
```

I did the concurrency management myself as i wanted to get as much performance out of the bean as i could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to do this in the bean itself?

I suppose you mean this:

```
@MessageDriven(...)
public MDBean implements MessageListener {
     private Statistic statisticForThisBean;
     // ...

     @Timeout
     public void sendStatisticForThisBean() {
         // ...
     }
}
```

It's certainly **not an option**. There's no guarantee that the `@Timeout`-annotated method will run for all bean instances **at all**, not to mention your requirement of running every 30 seconds. The timeout method runs on one of free instances of an MDB, and the container chooses it.

> Is it possible to do the statistic stuff centralised?

Personally, I'd do it this way: have all MDBs (all instances) send partial statistics to a queue, at the end of their processing logic. I'd write a separate component that would:

- exist in one instance only,
- collect all messages from the statistics queue for 30 seconds (in a loop), producing a summary, then sending it to the final destination, then restart.

The "component" could be a timer task, or a separate stand-alone application.

Another possible solution could be a single stateful bean, that MDBs would call in turn to update statistics. However, the following limitations apply:

- it's likely to cause performance problems, unless SFSB methods calls are fast (i.e. when the statistics are not complicated),
- it can't be run asynchronously, so you can't guarantee the 30 seconds span between calls to the statistic-gathering engine; if the JMS traffic stops completely, so the SFSB will stop responding, too.

Comment: would a singleton ejb with @asyncronous annotation serve the purpose of the internal queue? i want to avoid messaging because our jms broker is a remote server.

Comment: @Laures It would, but not in EJB 3.0/JBoss 6. It's an EJB 3.1 feature.

Comment: i believed that jboss 6.1 supports the async annotation?

Comment: @Laures Forget it, sorry. Since you tagged the question with "ejb-3.0", I thought you were looking for a solution within the specification. For the JBoss part, I can't give you any advice.

Comment: @Laures Added SFSB paragraph.

Comment: @Laures even if your msg provider is external, there's still the internal one from JBoss/Java EE. An asynchronous singleton is probably better (it's clearer there's only 1 instance here). Can you retag your question as ejb-3.1?

Comment: added my implemented solution to the question. seams to work so far. i still need to check if its fast enough for my message load.

Comment: @MaDa as far as i can say right now, everything works like it should and with a performance thats ok for now.